# Majority rule definition

Tags: genetics, definitions

In [this book](https://books.google.ca/books?id=P2vpuUJnTfgC&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&dq=majority%20rule%20structure%20genetics&source=bl&ots=EtmukQlbpN&sig=x2fblsTZksjOSkUh1lOv9kGCN7c&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXteO7i5XTAhWK34MKHXx7CaU4ChDoAQgiMAA#v=onepage&q=majority%20rule%20structure%20genetics&f=false), they talk about the `majority rule`.

> Majority rule, which retain s the edges present in more than 50% of the trees.

They used that rule also in this article (Grant, P. R., and B. R. Grant. 2010. Conspecific versus heterospecific gene exchange between populations of Darwin's finches. Philosophical transactions of the Royal Society of London. Series B, Biological sciences 365:1065–1076.)

> We applied the majority rule (p . 0.500) to assign individuals to
>   groups.

This was when using the software `STRUCTURE`.

I haven't found a convincing definition of the "majority rule" except definition in politics.

So what is the "majority rule" and how is it applied?

Comment: Majority rule is a binary decision rule that attributes an individual a category or rank based on the majority. I think you would get a fairly comprehensive answer if you asked this on stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: There's also an interesting example of judges voting for skaters [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=cWRgUyIpEbwC&pg=PA290&lpg=PA290&dq=majority+rule+statistics&source=bl&ots=sUrJSM4Raj&sig=dm72EzNFtCqq1VYS_9svgU5B8kc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW0MDw3JbTAhUB6GMKHTM5AXE4ChDoAQgZMAA#v=onepage&q=majority%20rule%20statistics&f=false), but again it doesn't provide a clear definition (pg 288)